How can I query for files in SharePoint using Microsoft Graph and Linq like language?
I have a .Net Core application that we use to gather files from SharePoint, and then we import the data from those files into our DB. The SharePoint folders are updated regularly, and we again crawl the folders for the files. Everything works, but its a bit slow. This how we do it:

Run a query in the DB and get a list of file names that have already been imported.
As the Graph commands are running, I compare each file name to the list to see if we have already imported that file. If so, I skip it. If not, I add the file to the list of files to import.

While this does work, it gets slower the more files that are uploaded to SharePoint, because I still need to touch each file to see if I've already imported it.
I know I can search using Microsoft Graph, but I'm not sure how. I would like to do something similar to:
List<string> FileNamesImported
context.xxxxx.where(x => !FileNamesImported.Contains(x.fileName))

It would return a list of drives that I could then use to get the files. I need to do this in C#. Does anyone know how to do this?
FYI - I'm using application permissions and I know how to get the graph client working.
Thanks!

We can use the Microsoft Search API to search OneDrive and SharePoint content.
In C# we need to use Microsoft Graph SDK for this request.
I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with C#, so I found a sample code for your reference.
1.Set Up Your Project:
Ensure you have the Microsoft Graph SDK installed.
You can install it via NuGet Package Manager:
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph

2.Complete Example:
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private static string clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    private static string[] scopes = { "Files.Read.All", "Sites.Read.All" };

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {   
        //Use the InteractiveBrowserProvider for authentication
        var interactiveBrowserProvider = new InteractiveBrowserProvider(clientId, scopes);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserProvider);

        //Define the search query to look for files in OneDrive or SharePoint
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequestObject
        {
            Requests = new List<SearchRequest>
            {
                new SearchRequest
                {
                    EntityTypes = new List<EntityType> { EntityType.DriveItem },
                    Query = new SearchQuery
                    {
                        QueryString = "project report"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        //Send the search request and handle the response
        var searchResponse = await graphClient.Search.Query(searchRequest).Request().PostAsync();

        foreach (var result in searchResponse.Value)
        {
            foreach (var hit in result.HitsContainers.SelectMany(container => container.Hits))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found file: {hit.Resource.Name} at {hit.Resource.WebUrl}");
            }
        }
    }
}

